# Where to save lco templates for scrlttr2 letters?

Tags: installing, koma-script, templates, letters, scrlttr2

In the german [Koma Script Book](http://www.dante.de/index/Literatur/KOMA-Script.html) I read about the elegant way to predefine the personal address in a .lco file like this

#### ~/texmf/tex/latex/jd_private_v001.lco  # <- added answer here for other readers

```
\ProvidesFile{JohnDoePrivate.lco}[2012/04/11]
\setkomavar{fromname}{John Doe}
\setkomavar{signature}{John Doe}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Iceroad 4\\ Northpole}
...
```

And include it in the header of a letter like

#### ~/my/work/letters/letter.tex

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,%
JohnDoePrivate,version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\opening{Dear Peter,}

I just want to say "hi".

\closing{Best wishes}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

My first idea was to create one `.lco` per sender address like `JohnDoePrivate.lco`, `JohnDoeWork.lco` and store them global on my Linux system. But where?

If John moves I could create a `jd_private_v002.lco` and LaTeX will hopefully take the latest address. I could also use the old `.tex` files too, if I force LaTeX to use a special version.

Comment: Probably in `~/texmf/tex/latex/scrlettraddresses`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends to your system: Linux or Windows.

However, it is the same as creating an own package and saving it in the local TEXMF tree which can be for Linux

```
~/texmf/[TDS]
/usr/local/texmf/[TDS]
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/[TDS]
```

and so on. For MiKTeX you can [define own trees and add them to the root base](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).

And in all directories you have to create a [TDS (TeX Directory Structure)](http://tug.org/tds/), as Enrico already pointed out.

Comment: sorry, but `usr/local/` is not system wide.

Comment: @Herbert `/usr/local` *is* of course system wide, in the sense that any user can access it.

Comment: no, only local user in the subnet.

Comment: I placed the template to `~/texmf/tex/latex/JohnDoePrivate2.lco` and it works. I did not place it to `/usr/...` because I think private addresses should be saved in private directories.